# Why doesn't the asyncio add_reader callback fire I write to stdin via subprocess?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-asyncio

I wrote a Python 3.4 script which uses `asyncio` to continuously read data from `stdin`, transform the data, and write to `stdout`. Within the script I use:

```
loop.add_reader(sys.stdin, read_func)
```

in order to get my hands on the input data.

I've successfully tested this functionality by:

1) Using `mock` to patch `sys.stdin` with a file I've opened (known input):

```
with open('mock_stdin.txt', 'r') as file:
    with mock.patch('sys.stdin', file):
        <add reader and start loop>
```

2) Using terminal to simulate data written to stdin:

```
mkfifo pipe
python my_script.py <pipe 1>out.txt 2>err.txt &
cat mock_stdin.txt >pipe
```

However I cannot use the Python `subprocess` module to successfully interact with my script. What I've found is that the `add_reader` callback never fires. What I'm doing is:

```
with open('out.txt', 'w') as out, open('err.txt', 'w') as err:
    proc = Popen(['python', 'my_script.py'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=out, stderr=err)
    proc.stdin.write(bytes(string_data, 'ascii'))
    proc.stdin.flush()
```

The reason why I'm writing to `out` and `err` above is because I was getting caught in deadlocks waiting for a response, so I write to disk for debugging purposes.

What I've found is that invoking `proc.stdin.write` does not fire the callback registered for `loop.add_reader`. However if I replace `stdin` argument of `Popen` with another file read from disk, then it will work just fine.

What am I missing here?

Comment: [as far as I remember](https://gist.github.com/nathan-hoad/8966377), it is not trivial to make asyncio stdio work for a tty, pipe, and file cases simultaneously. Unlrelated: you second case is a named pipe (that should behave exactly the same as pipe), not a tty.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian thank you for commenting. which of my cases above are a tty? I wrote another script which simply does `print(sys.stdin.isatty())`and the output is False for all 3 scenarios.

Comment: none, that is the point: the 1st is file, the 2nd and 3rd are pipe cases. You said "terminal" for the 2nd case.

Comment: @trianta2 How do you read from `sys.stdin` in `my_script.py`? `sys.stdin` is a `TextIOWrapper` object by default. A `TextIOWrapper` is **always buffered**, and buffered I/O don't play well with async callbacks.

Comment: @trianta2 If that was the problem, reopening `sys.stdin` with `open(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'rb', buffering=0)` shall fix it.

Comment: I've found that I was incorrect; the read callback was being fired. However the callback was blocking. Within the callback, I was reading all lines provided by subprocess with `lines = [line for line in sys.stdin]`. What appears to be happening is the code blocks, and the iterator never terminates. The same blocking behavior occurs with `sys.stdin.readlines()`. Once again this only happens with subprocess; files do not block. I noticed that if I close the subprocess stdin, then the callback will return. Perhaps it is waiting for EOF? I cannot close stdin in my application however.